# Rails 3.2 + Facebook auth + CSRF FAILURE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, facebook-oauth

This is the error that I see when trying to login via facebook, I always see that error. Can't seem to get rid of it:

> Could not authorize you from Facebook because "Csrf detected".

I put a skip:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

on the Omniauth callback, but still I get the error. This is in both local and prod (heroku) environments. I have set the heroku environment variables. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the problem was the gem was too new and passing a STATE header to facebook, which fb didn't want. I rolled the omniauth-facebook gem version back and it worked

Comment: Which version did you roll back to?

Comment: I had the same problem, downgrading omniauth-facebook to 1.4.0 solved the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/75 and https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/20 for some more details

Comment: Note: CSRF in Rails is not the same as CSRF using oauth. Those are two distinct systems trying to prevent CSRF, that is why the skip_before_filter doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue you have on the same day!!
I thought it was a gem update or something like this but not at all.
With a deep debugging I found that omniauth "Callback phase initiated." was called twice.

It was due to a stupid double initialization of

> provider :facebook, .....

One in config/initializers/devise.rb and in another initializer.

I hope it will give you an hint to find your error

Comment: I found that the problem was the gem was too new and passing a STATE header to facebook, which fb didn't want. I rolled the omniauth-facebook gem version back and it worked.

Comment: I was having this problem with another omniauth provider and could not figure it out until seeing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending a p3p header maybe add...

```
before_filter :set_p3p
private

def set_p3p
  headers['P3P'] = 'CP="ALL DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND COM NAV"'
end
```

to your application controller